# Is there a right way to build a URL?

Tags: java, url, uri

In much of the code I work with there is horrible stuff like:

```
String url = "../Somewhere/SomeServlet?method=AMethod&id="+object.getSomething()+ "&aParam="+object.getSomethingElse());
```

or - even worse:

```
String url = "Somewhere/Here/Something.jsp?path="+aFile.toString().replace("\\","/")+ "&aParam="+object.getSomethingElse());
```

Is there a right way to:

1. Create a new URL (or is it a URI).
2. Add correctly escaped parameters to it.
3. Add well-formed file paths in those params.
4. Resolve it to a String.

Essentially - it is too easy to just build the string than it is to do it properly. Is there a way to do it *properly* that is as easy as just building the string?

**Added**

For clarity - and after a little thought - I suppose I am looking for something like:

```
String s = new MyThing()
    .setPlace("Somewhere/Something.jsp")
    .addParameter(aName,aValue)
    .addParameter(aName,aFile)
    .toString();
```

so that it will deal with all of the unpleasantness of escaping and adding "?"/"&" and changing "\" to "/" instead of using "\" for files etc.

If I have to write one myself (i.e. if Apache is not an option) are there real Java techniques for correctly escaping the various parts. I mean things like escaping " " in parameters as "." while escaping " " in other places a "%20".

Comment: I think this seems similar.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1861620/is-there-a-java-package-to-handle-building-urls

Comment: Also, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/883136/is-there-a-good-url-builder-for-java

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I have written this up, you can change it where you want extra functionality. It doesn't use any external resources, let me know if I have looked over something!

It's basically a wrapper for the `URI` class that allows you to more easily add subdirectories and parameters to the URI. You can set default values if you're not interested in some things.

Edit: I have added an option to use a relative URI (per your question).

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws URISyntaxException,
            MalformedURLException {
        URLBuilder urlb = new URLBuilder("www.example.com");
        urlb.setConnectionType("http");
        urlb.addSubfolder("somesub");
        urlb.addSubfolder("anothersub");
        urlb.addParameter("param lol", "unknown");
        urlb.addParameter("paramY", "known");
        String url = urlb.getURL();
        System.out.println(url);


        urlb = new URLBuilder();
        urlb.addSubfolder("servlet");
        urlb.addSubfolder("jsp");
        urlb.addSubfolder("somesub");
        urlb.addSubfolder("anothersub");
        urlb.addParameter("param lol", "unknown");
        urlb.addParameter("paramY", "known");
        String relUrl = urlb.getRelativeURL();
        System.out.println(relUrl);
    }
}

class URLBuilder {
    private StringBuilder folders, params;
    private String connType, host;

    void setConnectionType(String conn) {
        connType = conn;
    }

    URLBuilder(){
        folders = new StringBuilder();
        params = new StringBuilder();
    }

    URLBuilder(String host) {
        this();
        this.host = host;
    }

    void addSubfolder(String folder) {
        folders.append("/");
        folders.append(folder);
    }

    void addParameter(String parameter, String value) {
        if(params.toString().length() > 0){params.append("&");}
        params.append(parameter);
        params.append("=");
        params.append(value);
    }

    String getURL() throws URISyntaxException, MalformedURLException {
        URI uri = new URI(connType, host, folders.toString(),
                params.toString(), null);
        return uri.toURL().toString();
    }

    String getRelativeURL() throws URISyntaxException, MalformedURLException{
        URI uri = new URI(null, null, folders.toString(), params.toString(), null);
        return uri.toString();
    }
}
```

Output:

**Absolute**

> http://www.example.com/somesub/anothersub?param%20lol=unknown&paramY=known

**Relative**

> /servlet/jsp/somesub/anothersub?param%20lol=unknown&paramY=known

Comment: I eventually used a variant of this technique [like this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19541585/823393).

Comment: This is NOT correct as it does not escape parameters or paths!

Comment: I would follow the answers pointing to the Apache and Spring URI builders.  That code will be well used and covered by tests!

Answer (score 72):

You can use [Apache URIBuilder](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/client/utils/URIBuilder.html)

Sample code: [Full Apache Example](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/shindig/trunk/java/common/src/test/java/org/apache/shindig/common/uri/UriBuilderTest.java)

```
URIBuilder builder = new URIBuilder()
    .setScheme("http")
    .setHost("apache.org")
    .setPath("/shindig")
    .addParameter("helloWorld", "foo&bar")
    .setFragment("foo");
builder.toString();
```

Output: http://apache.org/shindig?helloWorld=foo%26bar#foo

Comment: It's `URIBuilder`, not `UriBuilder`. Last URL is not valid, and I'd remove link to that example.

Comment: This also works with only query parameter, in case you already have a predefined base URL

Answer (score 39):

You can also use spring [UriComponentsBuilder](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/util/UriComponentsBuilder.html)

```
UriComponentsBuilder
    .fromUriString(baseUrl)
    .queryParam("name", name)
    .queryParam("surname", surname)
    .build().toUriString();
```

Comment: Be aware that this doesn't encode each query param so you need to do manually https://stackoverflow.com/a/21259193/524588

Comment: @SanghyunLee: instead you can follow https://www.baeldung.com/spring-uricomponentsbuilder  and use .build().encode().toUriString().

Answer (score 1):

I like @Jeroen's suggestion but it didn't quite do all I wanted so, using his idea of gathering the parts together and then using a `URI` to grow the final result I put together this solution which seems to do what I want:

```
public class URLBuilder {
  // The scheme - http
  private String scheme = null;
  // The user - user
  private String user = null;
  // The host - example.com
  private String host = null;
  // The port - 8080
  private int port = -1;
  // The paths - /Path/To/Somewhere/index.jsp
  private final ArrayList<String> paths = new ArrayList<String>();
  // The parameters - ?a=b&c=d
  private final ArrayList<Pair<String, String>> queries = new ArrayList<Pair<String, String>>();
  // The fragment - #n
  private String fragment = null;

  public URLBuilder addQuery(String name, String value) {
    queries.add(new Pair(name, value));
    return this;
  }

  public URLBuilder addQuery(String name, long value) {
    addQuery(name, String.valueOf(value));
    return this;
  }

  public URLBuilder addQuery(String name, File file) {
    addQuery(name, file.toURI().getPath());
    return this;
  }

  public URLBuilder addPath(String path) {
    paths.add(path);
    return this;
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    // Build the path.
    StringBuilder path = new StringBuilder();
    for (String p : paths) {
      path.append("/").append(p);
    }
    // Build the query.
    StringBuilder query = new StringBuilder();
    String sep = "";
    for (Pair<String, String> p : queries) {
      query.append(sep).append(p.p).append("=").append(p.q);
      sep = "&";
    }
    String url = null;
    try {
      URI uri = new URI(
              scheme,
              user,
              host,
              port,
              path.length() > 0 ? path.toString() : null,
              query.length() > 0 ? query.toString() : null,
              fragment);
      url = uri.toString();
    } catch (URISyntaxException ex) {
      Logger.getLogger(URLBuilder.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

    return url;
  }

  /**
   * @param host the host to set
   * @return this
   */
  public URLBuilder setHost(String host) {
    this.host = host;
    return this;
  }

  /**
   * @param scheme the scheme to set
   * @return this
   */
  public URLBuilder setScheme(String scheme) {
    this.scheme = scheme;
    return this;
  }

  /**
   * @param user the user to set
   * @return this
   */
  public URLBuilder setUser(String user) {
    this.user = user;
    return this;
  }

  /**
   * @param port the port to set
   * @return this
   */
  public URLBuilder setPort(int port) {
    this.port = port;
    return this;
  }

  /**
   * @param fragment the fragment to set
   * @return this
   */
  public URLBuilder setFragment(String fragment) {
    this.fragment = fragment;
    return this;
  }

  public static void main(String args[]) {
    try {
      URLBuilder url = new URLBuilder();
      System.out.println(url.toString());
      url.setFragment("fragment");
      System.out.println(url.toString());
      url.setHost("host.com");
      System.out.println(url.toString());
      url.addPath("APath");
      System.out.println(url.toString());
      url.addPath("AnotherPath");
      System.out.println(url.toString());
      url.addQuery("query1", "param1");
      System.out.println(url.toString());
      url.addQuery("query 2", "param 2");
      System.out.println(url.toString());
      url.addQuery("file", new File("Hello World.txt"));
      System.out.println(url.toString());
    } catch (Throwable t) {
      t.printStackTrace(System.err);
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: Could you clarify what functionality you have added? Glad I could help :)

Comment: @JeroenVannevel - I added the handling of `File` as queries and a more complete use of the `URI` class. I plan to mark your answer as correct as it inspired my builder. I am waiting for any late but inspiring suggestions.

Answer (score -6):

Recomendations

```
private final String BASE_URL = Properties.getProperty("base-url");

private Map propertiesMap; // = new HashMap<String,String>();
```

and in the code to build the URL.

```
public String buildURL(){
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    builder.append(BASE_URL);
    //for each property, append it

    return builder.toString();

}
```

Comment: Downvoting, because this is only half-baked code that re-invents the wheel. Also it doesn't address all requirements of the OP.