# Strange url encoding issue

Tags: java, urlencode

I have a strange issue with urlencoding a plus sign `+` as a query param for a request against an API. The API's documentation states:

> The date has to be in the W3C format, e.g. '2016-10-24T13:33:23+02:00'.

So far so good, so I'm using this code (minimalized) to generate the url, using Spring's UriComponentBuilder:

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssX");
ZonedDateTime dateTime = ZonedDateTime.now().minusDays(1);
String formated = dateTime.format(formatter);

UriComponentsBuilder uriComponentsBuilder = UriComponentsBuilder.fromUriString(baseUrl);
uriComponentsBuilder.queryParam("update", formated);
uriComponentsBuilder.build();
String url = uriComponentsBuilder.toUriString();
```

---

The unencoded query would look like this:

```
https://example.com?update=2017-01-05T12:40:44+01
```

---

The encoded string results in:

```
https://example.com?update=2017-01-05T12:40:44%2B01
```

which is (IMHO) a correctly encoded query String. See the `%2B` replacing the `+` in `+01` at the end of the query string.

Now, however, when I send the request against the API using the encoded url, I get an error saying the request could not be handled.

If however, I replace the `%2B` with a `+` before sending the request, it works:

```
url.replaceAll("%2B", "+");
```

From my understanding, the `+` sign is a replacement for a `whitespace`. So the url that the server really sees after decoding must be

```
https://example.com?update=2017-01-05T12:40:44 01
```

- Am I right with this assumption?
- Is there anything I can do, other than contacting the API's owner to make it work using the correctly encoded query, other than strange non standard string replacements?

UPDATE:

According to the specification [RFC 3986](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3986.txt) (Section 3.4), the `+` sign in a query param doesn't need to be encoded.

> 3.4.  Query
>
> The query component contains non-hierarchical data that, along with
>   data in the path component (Section 3.3), serves to identify a
>   resource within the scope of the URI's scheme and naming authority
>   (if any).  The query component is indicated by the first question
>   mark ("?") character and terminated by a number sign ("#") character
>   or by the end of the URI.
>
> Berners-Lee, et al.         Standards Track                    [Page
>   23]  RFC 3986                   URI Generic Syntax
>   January 2005
>
> ```
>   query       = *( pchar / "/" / "?" )
> ```
>
> The characters slash ("/") and question mark ("?") may represent
>   data    within the query component.  Beware that some older, erroneous
>   implementations may not handle such data correctly when it is used as 
>   the base URI for relative references (Section 5.1), apparently
>   because they fail to distinguish query data from path data when
>   looking for hierarchical separators.  However, as query components
>   are often used to carry identifying information in the form of
>   "key=value" pairs and one frequently used value is a reference to
>   another URI, it is sometimes better for usability to avoid percent-
>   encoding those characters.

According to [this answer on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18138011/url-encoding-using-the-new-spring-uricomponentsbuilder/#21460758), spring's UriComponentBuilder uses this specification, but appearently it doesn't really. So a new question would be, how to make UriComponentBuilder follow the specs?

Comment: Refer to the table provided by @Simon Tewsi  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/575440/url-encoding-using-c-sharp

Comment: @Prabu, Your reference does not answer the question. OP wants to know why the service accepts only the unencoded plus sign, not how to encode or not, or what C# utilities to use. A quick check of encoding rules indicates that the circumstances under which reserved characters are or must be encoded has changed slightly, but I haven't seen anything to suggest that the plus sign, used as part of a formatted date string, shouldn't be encoded.

Comment: That's exactly what I think too @arcy

Comment: @Michael, `UriComponentsBuilder.build()` has one version with an encoding flag and one version without. The one without, which you are using, does not say (in the version of javadoc I looked at) whether it defaults to encoded or not. You don't indicate whether you have seen the resulting strings or are just assuming they are the output. Is it possible it isn't encoding and you haven't realized it?

Comment: No, I logged them several times. @arcy I'm sure they are exactly as shown

Comment: P.S. setting the encoding flag doesn't change it. As well as using normalize(), encode() doesn't change the behaviour. @arcy

Comment: `urlBuilder.queryParam("redirect_uri", URLEncoder.encode(redirectURI,"UTF-8" ));` Try sepecifying the charset to UTF-8

Comment: I commented lot before you made a edit to the post. You edited 9 mins ago and I posted my comment 10 mins ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it seems like spring's UriComponentBuilder encodes the whole url, setting the encoding flag to `false` in the `build()` method has no effect, because the `toUriString()` method allways encodes the url, as it calls `encode()` explicitly after `build()`:

```
/**
 * Build a URI String. This is a shortcut method which combines calls
 * to {@link #build()}, then {@link UriComponents#encode()} and finally
 * {@link UriComponents#toUriString()}.
 * @since 4.1
 * @see UriComponents#toUriString()
 */
public String toUriString() {
    return build(false).encode().toUriString();
}
```

The solution for me (for now) is encoding what really needs to be encoded manually. Another solution could be (might require encoding too) getting the URI and work with that further on

```
String url = uriComponentsBuilder.build().toUri().toString(); // returns the unencoded url as a string
```

Comment: This does not work when using `UriComponentsBuilder.fromUriString(baseUrl)` and this baseUrl already contains encoded query params. In that case `uriComponentsBuilder.build().toUri().toString();` does encode already encoded characters again. This is especially the case if you would use something like `ServletUriComponentsBuilder.fromCurrentRequest().build().toString()`.

Comment: Now it seems they have changed the behavior to call encode() first followed by build(). Which will cause `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Mismatched open and close braces` if you have a value like "{{{{" in one of your query strings.

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-web/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/util/UriComponentsBuilder.java#L445

Answer (score 1):

you can use **`builder.build().toUriString()`**

This worked for me

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Encoding `2017-01-05T12:40:44+01`

gives you `2017-01-05T12%3A40%3A44%2B01`

instead of `2017-01-05T12:40:44%2B01` as you suggested.

Maybe that's why the server is not being able to handle your request, it's a half encoded date.

Comment: No, that's not the problem

Answer (score 0):

In the org/springframework/web/util/HierarchicalUriComponents.java

```
QUERY_PARAM {
        @Override
        public boolean isAllowed(int c) {
            if ('=' == c || '+' == c || '&' == c) {
                return false;
            }
            else {
                return isPchar(c) || '/' == c || '?' == c;
            }
        }
    }
```

the character '+' is not allowed so it will be encoded

Comment: you can use builder.build().toUriString()