# Why are urls encoded other than specified by RFC3986 by spring and apache

Tags: java, spring, encoding, urlencode, apache-commons

Earlier today I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41505241/strange-url-encoding-issue) about an url encoding problem.

I was trying to encode url query params with spring's UriComponentBuilder, then I also tried apache commons' UriBuilder. Both encode a plus sign (`+`) within a query param as `%2B`, but according to [the specification RFC3986](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3986.txt) (Section 3.4), a plus sign is permitted in the query params. Not permitted are only:

> *( pchar / "/" / "?" )

So this would be a valid url

```
http://www.example.com?foo=bar+baz
```

But both libraries convert the +:

```
http://www.example.com?foo=bar%2Bbaz
```

I never heard of that before and assumed that a `+` is in fact an encoded `whitespace` character. In addition, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21460758/7321467) states that at least spring follows that spec.

Who is right? The specification, or spring and apache? Or do I simply misunderstand something? Or which specification is followed by those libs?

Sidenote

I would even consider it bad practice to not allow and not parse the encoded character server side, would you agree?

Comment: The specification may be more lenient (not sure), but that does not mean that spring or apache are wrong; they are just more strict.

Comment: That was one of my thoughts too. @MarkRotteveel -- I would even consider it bad practice to not allow the encoded character server side, would you agree?